# vsftpd virtual users

Tags: ftp

is there a way for me to give each user their own userid? because right now any users that logins whenever he creates a file creates under ftp user

on my other system i use proftpd and each user has its own id even though all users are virtual as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused. Most *nix filesystems save the user as the UID number, which is then translated back to a username by the system. (Via PAM or straight from /etc/passwd in the most simple case). In order for the filesystem to be able to reflect the username used to log into the ftp server, that user would have to be available system wide, not just to the ftp server.

What I'm trying to say, is that I don't see how you can have purely virtual ftp users create files on the system with their own UID. I would look closely at the proftpd system to see how its working. For example, on a GNU linux system, running `ls -n` will print out the directory listing showing the numeric UID, instead of the username. Then take a look in /etc/passwd and make sure there is nothing listed for that UID.

Comment: i'm able to get it to work w/ proftpd no problem each user has its own userid and groupid, and even if system doesnt know anything it will still assign it for example chown 1043:1028

Comment: Oh. I think I follow you now. So on that system, a normal `ls` command doesn't show the username, just the UID. That's a little weird. Sorry, no idea how to get vsftpd to replicate that, but for some reason that setup feels a little "dirty".